# Installing Icecast on OS X: Homebrew or MacPorts?

Tags: macos, homebrew, macports, icecast

I've been trying to run an `Icecast` server for a while, without success.

I've installed it with `Homebrew` and `MacPorts`, but can't make it run either way.

When I enter `icecast -c ~/.icecast.xml`, Terminal doesn't return anything, and it stays like that indefinitely, unless I `[1]+  Stopped` it.

My config file `icecast.xml` was downloaded from [this tutorial](http://dzello.com/blog/2012/11/21/live-stream-audio-from-osx-mountain-lion-with-icecast-and-darkice/), though I'm using OS X Mavericks (10.9).

I haven't changed a single line of code from it. I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

```
<icecast>
<!-- location and admin are two arbitrary strings that are e.g. visible
     on the server info page of the icecast web interface
     (server_version.xsl). -->
<location>Earth</location>
<admin>admin@localhost</admin>

<limits>
    <clients>100</clients>
    <sources>2</sources>
    <threadpool>5</threadpool>
    <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
    <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
    <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
    <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
    <!-- If enabled, this will provide a burst of data when a client 
         first connects, thereby significantly reducing the startup 
         time for listeners that do substantial buffering. However,
         it also significantly increases latency between the source
         client and listening client.  For low-latency setups, you
         might want to disable this. -->
    <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
    <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for bre eing more
         specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
         change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
    <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
</limits>

<authentication>
    <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
    <source-password>hackme</source-password>
    <!-- Relays log in username 'relay' -->
    <relay-password>hackme</relay-password>

    <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
    <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
    <admin-password>hackme</admin-password>
</authentication>

<!-- set the mountpoint for a shoutcast source to use, the default if not
     specified is /stream but you can change it here if an alternative is
     wanted or an extension is required
<shoutcast-mount>/live.nsv</shoutcast-mount>
-->

<!-- Uncomment this if you want directory listings -->
<!--
<directory>
    <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
    <yp-url>http://dir.xiph.org/cgi-bin/yp-cgi</yp-url>
</directory>
 -->

<!-- This is the hostname other people will use to connect to your server.
It affects mainly the urls generated by Icecast for playlists and yp
listings. -->
<hostname>stream.myhouse.com</hostname>

<!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
<listen-socket>
    <port>8000</port>
    <!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->
    <!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
</listen-socket>
<!--
<listen-socket>
    <port>8001</port>
</listen-socket>
-->

<!--<master-server>127.0.0.1</master-server>-->
<!--<master-server-port>8001</master-server-port>-->
<!--<master-update-interval>120</master-update-interval>-->
<!--<master-password>hackme</master-password>-->

<!-- setting this makes all relays on-demand unless overridden, this is
     useful for master relays which do not have <relay> definitions here.
     The default is 0 -->
<!--<relays-on-demand>1</relays-on-demand>-->

<!--
<relay>
    <server>127.0.0.1</server>
    <port>8001</port>
    <mount>/example.ogg</mount>
    <local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
    <on-demand>0</on-demand>

    <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
</relay>
-->

<!-- Only define a <mount> section if you want to use advanced options,
     like alternative usernames or passwords
<mount>
    <mount-name>/example-complex.ogg</mount-name>

    <username>othersource</username>
    <password>hackmemore</password>

    <max-listeners>1</max-listeners>
    <dump-file>/tmp/dump-example1.ogg</dump-file>
    <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
    <fallback-mount>/example2.ogg</fallback-mount>
    <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
    <fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>
    <intro>/example_intro.ogg</intro>
    <hidden>1</hidden>
    <no-yp>1</no-yp>
    <authentication type="htpasswd">
            <option name="filename" value="myauth"/>
            <option name="allow_duplicate_users" value="0"/>
    </authentication>
    <on-connect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-start</on-connect>
    <on-disconnect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-stop</on-disconnect>
</mount>

<mount>
    <mount-name>/auth_example.ogg</mount-name>
    <authentication type="url">
        <option name="mount_add"

    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
        <option name="mount_remove"       
    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
        <option name="listener_add"    
    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
        <option name="listener_remove" 
    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
    </authentication>
</mount>

-->

<fileserve>1</fileserve>

<paths>
    <!-- basedir is only used if chroot is enabled -->
    <basedir>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.3.3/share/icecast</basedir>

    <!-- Note that if <chroot> is turned on below, these paths must both
         be relative to the new root, not the original root -->
    <logdir>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.3.3/var/log/icecast</logdir>
    <webroot>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.3.3/share/icecast/web</webroot>
    <adminroot>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.3.3/share/icecast/admin</adminroot>
    <!-- <pidfile>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.3.3/share/icecast/icecast.pid</pidfile> - ->

    <!-- Aliases: treat requests for 'source' path as being for 'dest' path
         May be made specific to a port or bound address using the "port"
         and "bind-address" attributes.
      -->
    <!--
    <alias source="/foo" destination="/bar"/>
      -->
    <!-- Aliases: can also be used for simple redirections as well,
         this example will redirect all requests for http://server:port/ to
         the status page
      -->
    <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
</paths>

<logging>
    <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
    <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
    <!-- <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog> -->
    <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
    <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
    <!-- If logarchive is enabled (1), then when logsize is reached
         the logfile will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.DATESTAMP,
         otherwise it will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.old.
         Default is non-archive mode (i.e. overwrite)
    -->
    <!-- <logarchive>1</logarchive> -->
</logging>

<security>
    <!-- <chroot>0</chroot> -->
    <!--
    <changeowner>
        <user>nobody</user>
        <group>nogroup</group>
    </changeowner>
    -->
</security>
</icecast>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install Icecast using Homebrew, the default configuration file will be placed at `/usr/local/etc/icecast.xml`, just edit it as you need.
I did not read your config, but it might be that there is an error in it somewhere, so just use the example config that is shipped with Icecast.

Comment: Oh and don't forget to change the default passwords!